# Error C2660: 'strcpy_s': function does not take 2 arguments

Tags: c++

Я не могу понять в чем моя ошибка. Добавила "_s", не помогает. Появляется другая ошибка: Error C2660: 'strcpy_s': function does not take 2 arguments

```
public:
TGoods() : year_(0), name_(NULL)
{
}
TGoods(int year, const char *name): year_(year),name_(strcpy_s(new char[strlen(name) + 1], name))
{
}
```

Comment: А какая была первая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, функция `strcpy_s` в С++ может принимать два аргумента только в том случае, если ее первый аргумент - массив. У вас первый аргумент - не массив, а указатель. В такой случае аргументов придется передавать *три*: дополнительно придется передать размер буфера-приемника. Все это ясно описано в документации к функции `strcpy_s`. Неясно, почему вы пользуетесь незнакомой функцией `strcpy_s` и при этом даже не пытаетесь почитать документацию.

Во-вторых, использование функции `strcpy` формально ошибкой не является. Ваш компилятор сам сказал вам, как отключить это назойливое и странное сообщение об ошибке. Прямо там, в сообщении об ошибке вам сказано, что это можно сделать через определение макроса `_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` (и, заодно, `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`). Лучше всего это делать глобально, в настройках проекта

```
Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions
```

Comment: Вы очень помогли! Спасибо большое!

Comment: это все правильно, но в случаи с  strcpy ничего не понятно: не вижу повода для предупреждений

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Это известное поведение компилятора в Visual Studio, о котором тут уже много раз писали. При включенных "SDL Checks" использование `strcpy` будет "ошибкой", при выключенных - "предупреждением".

Comment: @AnT, я впервые слышу. А предупреждение какого рода, что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Ну все верно, на то она и безопасная, чтоб кроме как "куда", еще и проверять "сколько".

В вашем варианте я бы смело использовал `strcpy` - и так понятно, что вы выделяете достаточно памяти. Но если нет, то...

```
name_(nullptr) ...

{
    strcpy_s(name_= new char[strlen(name) + 1], strlen(name) + 1, name));
```

Comment: Я не смогу использовать просто strcpy, так как тоже выдает ошибку, и говорит нужно использовать strcpy_s. Ваш вариант тоже не помог...

Comment: Еще раз - какую ошибку? Может, просто предупреждение?

Comment: Выдает такую ошибку: error C2440: 'initializing': can not convert from 'errno_t' to 'char*'

Comment: Блин, ну да, совсем забыл... Вот так - перенесите его в тело конструктора. Но - еще раз - здесь вполне безопасно использовать `strcpy`, как вы и делали сначала. Вам выдавали не ошибку, а *предупреждение*, что желательно бы... Если уж очень не хочется читать это предупреждение - добавьте в начало файла строку `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

Comment: @Susha: Вы что-то выдумываете. Никакого `errno` в приведенном вами коде нет и в помине.

Comment: Спасибо за то, что Вы попытались помочь!

Comment: @AnT `strcpy_s` возвращает не указатель, а [ошибку](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx), все ли в порядке. Так что тут все верно.

Comment: @Harry: А, точно! "Знал, но забыл". Спасибо.

Comment: @AnT Вот так и я с самого начала посоветовал не тот код, забывши...