# Указатель на указатель + динамическое выделение памяти (помогите исправить ошибку)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Вот функция, которая должна выделять динамическую память для новых элементов массива указателей и  для хранения символов новых строк. Эта функция должна принимать, как параметры, указатель на указатель, размер массива указателей и строку, которую надо будет записать в выделенную под нее память.
Но Visual Studio 2017 выдаёт две ошибки при сборке:
 1. "Ошибка C2660 strcpy_s: функция не принимает 2 аргументов".
 2. "Ошибка (активно) E0304 отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "strcpy_s", соответствующие списку аргументов".
 Подскажите и объясните пожалуйста, что нужно исправить, чтоб программка скомпилировалась.

Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>;
#include <string.h>;

using namespace std;

char **AddPtr(char **pp, int size, char *str); //прототип функции

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

int size = 0;//количество указателей на строки
char **pp = 0;//указатель на массив указателей, которые содержат адреса 
строк

cout << "~~~~~Добавляем указатели на пять строк и заполняем строки 
данными~~~~~" << endl;
//вызов функции и присваивание возвращаемого значения
pp = AddPtr(pp, size, "11111111111111111");
size++; //=1  увеличиваем размер массива указателей

pp = AddPtr(pp, size, "22222222222222222");
size++;  //2

pp = AddPtr(pp, size, "33333333333333333");
size++;  //3

pp = AddPtr(pp, size, "44444444444444444");
size++;  //4

pp = AddPtr(pp, size, "55555555555555555");
size++;  //5

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)    //показываем все строки на экран
    cout << pp[i] << endl;  //достаточно обратиться к pp[i] - это адрес 
строки (0-й элемент)
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //освобождаем память
{
    delete[] pp[i]; // сначала выделенную под строки      
}
delete[] pp; // потом выделенную под массив указателей
return 0;
}

char **AddPtr(char **pp, int size, char *str)
{
if (size == 0) {
    pp = new char *[size + 1]; //выделяем память для указателя на строку
}
else {   //если массив уже не пустой, данные надо скопировать во временный 
массив **copy
    char **copy = new char*[size + 1]; //создаем временный массив
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //копируем в него адреса уже определенных 
строк
    {
        copy[i] = pp[i];
    }
    //теперь строки хранятся в адресах copy

    delete[] pp; //освобождаем память, которая указывала на строки

    pp = copy; //показываем указателю на какие адреса теперь ссылаться
}

pp[size] = new char[strlen(str) + 1];  //выделяем память на новую строку
strcpy_s(pp[size], str);  //и копируем новую строку в элемент pp[size].

return pp;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy_s` вторым параметром принимает размер строки в которую будет произведено копирование. Добавьте в вызов `strcpy_s` второй аргумент: `strcpy_s(pp[size], strlen(str) + 1, str)`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828871/error-c2660-strcpy-s-function-does-not-take-2-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strcpy_s не принимает 2х аргументов, сигнатуру и примеры использования этой функции можете посмотреть [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)! предложенный в комментариях вариант

> Цитата: strcpy_s(pp[size], strlen(str) + 1, str)

выглядит работоспособным